# Cannot reset Keyring password

Tags: password, reset

I'm running 16.04. I am getting the pop up screen to enter my password but it keeps saying it's the wrong pass. I've tried using Seahorse to change the password by deleting the current situation and creating a new but I get the same results. I've even tried to use the Terminal and tried the following code that I found on the Ask
Ubuntu.

( Resetting everything (delete all passwords and start new keyring):

```
rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
```

Or

Navigate to Places > Home. Press Ctrl + H to view "hidden files". Navigate to .local > share > keyrings and delete login.keyring

Using the same keyring (resetting keyring password but keeping old passwords in keyring):

Make a backup of the keyring

```
cd ~/.local/share/keyrings/
cp login.keyring login.keyring.backup
```

and after that delete login.keyring file

```
rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
```

Create a new keyring file from Gnome Keyring with the name login
Replace the new keyring file with the backup of the old keyring file

```
cd ~/.local/share/keyrings/
mv login.keyring.backup login.keyring  )
```

But sadly it doesn't matter either. 
I've even tried to format my hardrive so I can install 18.04 but it's asking for my password.

How can I fix/debug this?

Answer (score 0):

If you were willing to go as far as formatting the hard-drive you could have just cleaned its partition table. Otherwise, and it still baffles me how there is not a better implementation for this, the solution is just to perform the same events you have performed, with the only difference being that you need to right click the login.keyring file and delete it in that fashion rather than running `rm` on it.

You can achieve this by either using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in the folder location or alternatively by right clicking the key ring within seahorse itself.